# FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-762 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap

I have a problem, I have 4 activities: A - B - C - D.

My application starts at A and goes to B, C and finally D, D I can choose to go back to A or B, if he goes to a B, I can go back to C, the problem is in sometimes **when I come ab (no problems) but when I go from B to C (when it completes the cycle) it gives this error**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-762 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate (Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:640)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java : 620) 
    at usuario.app.redavsalpha.MainActivity $ 2.run (MainActivity.java:555) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:856)
```

I've been searching and could not solve this problem, does anyone have any idea what can be?

Here is the piece of code that contains bitmap of activity C:

```
thread = new Thread() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(strURL).getContent());
            if(tempBitmap.getConfig()!=null)
            {
               config = tempBitmap.getConfig();
            }
            else
            {
            config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            }
            bitmapMaster = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight(), config);
            canvasMaster = new Canvas(bitmapMaster);
            canvasMaster.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            //para a aplicação a partir daqui debaixo
            bitmapDrawingPane = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight(), config);
            canvasDrawingPane = new Canvas(bitmapDrawingPane);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: You should always dispose your bitmaps when you're done drawing or they'll stay in memory. Look for memory leak android bitmap in google.

Comment: I see code where you're downloading some bitmap (strURL), more than likely a large one, then creating two additional sets of same size bitmaps and canvas objects.  Out of memory error is no surprise...

Comment: you think using: myBitmap.recycle (); 
It would be the correct way?